# Tikz library : command \draw ... to... with out and in specification

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to ask how the following command works:

```
\draw [] (0,0) to [out=20,in=120] (50,20) to [out=-60, in=110] (90,20);
```

I wonder what part .. `to [out=20,in=120]` .. makes.  The result is a curve, but I don't know how to properly understand these parameters.

Comment: This is explained in the manual, section titled "The To Path Operation" (14.14 in my version).  It would help if you explained what you don't understand from that explanation.

Comment: Look at the pgfmanual version October 25, 2010 section 51.3 Curves (reached almost immediately searching "out=").

Answer (score 31, accepted):

From the [pgfmanual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) :

> If you write `(a)  to  [out=135,in=45]  (b)` a curve is added to the path, which leaves at an angle
>   of 135°
>   at a and arrives at an angle of 45°
>   at b.  This is because the options in and out trigger a special
>   path to be used instead of the straight line.

This actually allows you to bend paths between two points. The angles are specified with respect to the horizontal line, or, if the option `relative` is passed, with respect to the straight line between the two points.

Consider the simple example below :
[image: Example]

The red curve is the result of `(a) to [out=20, in=120] (b)` as in your example.
The angles specified by the `out` and `in` parameters are described on the picture. An easy way to remember the parameters is that you specify the angle by which your curve is going *out* of the source node, and entering *in* the target node.

To understand the difference induced by the option relative, have a look at the following two examples : first without the option `relative`, so absolute angles :

[image]

And now with relative angles :

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[circle,draw] (a) at (0,0) {a};
  \node[circle,draw] (b) at (10,0) {b};
  \draw[dashed] (a) -- (b);
  \draw[dashed] (a) -- +(20:10cm);
  \draw[dashed] (b) -- +(120:4cm);
  \draw[dashed] (b) -- +(0:3cm);

  \draw (a) +(4,0)  arc (0:20:4);
  \draw (a) + (10:4.3) node {$20^{\circ}$};
  \draw (b) + (2,0) arc (0:120:2);
  \draw (b) + (60:2.3) node {$120^{\circ}$};

  \draw[red] (a) to[out=20,in=120] (b);
\end{tikzpicture}

\clearpage

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[circle,draw] (a) at (0,0) {a};
  \node[circle,draw] (b) at (0,5) {b};
  \draw[dashed] (a) -- +(0:5cm);
  \draw[dashed] (a) -- +(20:10cm);
  \draw[dashed] (b) -- +(120:4cm);
  \draw[dashed] (b) -- +(0:3cm);

  \draw (a) +(4,0)  arc (0:20:4);
  \draw (a) + (10:4.3) node {$20^{\circ}$};
  \draw (b) + (2,0) arc (0:120:2);
  \draw (b) + (60:2.3) node {$120^{\circ}$};

  \draw[red] (a) to[out=20,in=120] (b);
\end{tikzpicture}

\clearpage

\begin{tikzpicture}[relative]
  \node[circle,draw] (a) at (0,0) {a};
  \node[circle,draw] (b) at (0,5) {b};
  \draw[dashed] (a) -- (b);
  \draw[dashed] (a) -- +(110:10cm);
  \draw[dashed] (b) -- +(210:4cm);
  \draw[dashed] (b) -- +(90:3cm);

  \draw (a) +(0,2)  arc (90:110:2);
  \draw (a) + (100:2.3) node {$20^{\circ}$};
  \draw (b) + (0,2) arc (90:210:2);
  \draw (b) + (120:2.3) node {$120^{\circ}$};

  \draw[red] (a) to[out=20,in=120] (b);
\end{tikzpicture}  


\end{document}
```

### Acknowledgements

Thanks to Paul Gaborit for his remark regarding the option `relative`.

Comment: Without the option `relative`, the angles are absolute...

Comment: @PaulGaborit : Thanks, I completely forgot about that detail, and my example didn't help. I editted.

Comment: Thank you. I suspected that somewhere in the manual will be, but I was frustrated that I can not find it. Once again, thank you all for your help.